What are file watchers in an Angular app, and how to clean them up? (System limit for number of file watchers reached)
I have a simple Angular app, that is a collection of small example apps.
(The code can be found on GitHub, and the homepage is here.)
I work on it locally.
Suddenly the following error is all over my console, when I do ng serve:
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: ENOSPC:
System limit for number of file watchers reached,
watch '/home/tilman/Code/angular_examples/node_modules/blah/blah'
But the app still works. There seems to be no problem, except my flooded console.
Some details:
   Ubuntu 20.04
   PyCharm 2024.1.3 (Professional Edition)
   Angular CLI: 13.3.4
   Node: 17.9.0 (Unsupported, according to ng v)
   Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
   /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches: 65536
Similar questions have been asked about React in 2019 and about Angular in 2021.
The answers mostly sound like: Pressing some buttons worked for me.
But I would like to know what is going on here.
I was not aware, that file watchers are a thing.
Do I need them? Where are they? Why are there so many? How to clean them up?
One of the proposed solutions is deleting and reinstalling node_modules.
That is not a good way to solve problems. (What if something is gone, when I try to reinstall it?)
One answer to the React question sounds quite reasonable:
add watchOptions: { ignored: /node_modules/ } to webpack.config.js
I just don't have that file.
Initially the errors are for all kinds of folders in node_modules.
Eventually only these four are repeated in a loop:
/home/tilman/Code/angular_examples/node_modules/jquery/dist
/home/tilman/Code/angular_examples/node_modules/jquery
/home/tilman/Code/angular_examples/node_modules/typescript/lib
/home/tilman/Code/angular_examples/node_modules/typescript

Here is a screenshot, showing Compiled successfully among the error messages:


Edit: A popup in Pycharm sends me to this support page: Inotify Watches Limit (Linux)
There I am told, that I should just increase the number of allowed watchers.
A user asks about the same problem, also in an Angular project.
The answer is, that folders can not be excluded from watching.
But there is a proposal that users can vote for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-2175
Anyway, I have added node_modules to the excluded folders, and now the problem is gone. (It was already orange, but ulike dist and tmp it did not appear in the list.)


The solution is of course not to watch files in node_modules.
(Because nothing there is supposed to be changed.)
I have added it to the excluded folders in Pycharm. Apparently that worked.
(See screenshot at the end of the question.)
